# .NET is treating 24:00:00 as 24 days

Tags: c#, .net

Why TimeSpan **24:00:00** is treated as 24 days in .Net? I expect this to be 1 day?

```
Console.WriteLine($"24:00:00 - {TimeSpan.Parse("24:00:00")}");

24:00:00 - 24.00:00:00
```

Comment: Please elaborate what you mean by _"treated as 1 day"_. What do you expect to see? Why do you think this doesn't work? Perhaps the default is to print any hours < 25 as 24 hours, and after that as 1 day and N hours? I don't know, though, check MSDN to confirm your expectations.

Comment: @CodeCaster <code>TimeSpan.Parse("24:00:00").Days</code> is returning 24.

Comment: @EhsanSajjad I see 24 as valid value, it's just 1 day?

Comment: The correct way of specifying that `TimeSpan` is `1.00:00:00`. It's a little disappointing it doesn't give an error, as it *does* do if you explicitly try `0.24:00:00`. `24:00:00` is invalid for the same reason `00:78:00` is -- `TimeSpan` does not handle overflows to the next unit.

Comment: @Falaque that's fine, but my point was that this question is unclear. If the asker doesn't explain what they expect to see, it's up to us to guess what they mean, which is not quite productive.

Comment: @CodeCaster This is what I expect (s the default is to print any hours < 25 as 24 hours, and after that as 1 day and N hours?), but it's not true.

Comment: @CodeCaster I expect 24:00:00 to emit 1 day.

Comment: Then change your expectations, as the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/se73z7b9(v=vs.110).aspx) tells you the hour component of the string has to be 0-23. See the other comments and the duplicate: the parsing is liberally interpreting "24:00:00" as 24 days.

Comment: From the documentation : _"The s parameter contains a time interval specification in the form: [ws][-]{ d | [d.]hh:mm[:ss[.ff]] }[ws]"_ - as there is no dot or whitespace following the 24, then I would expect "24:00:00" to be parsed as hh:mm:ss - which should throw an exception.

Comment: I also agree 24:00:00 being treated as 24 hours is less intuitive, and may lead to another disaster (on funny note :-) http://www-users.math.umn.edu/~arnold/disasters/ariane.html). This should throw some sort of ArgumentException.